# SQL Command cannot be converted to string

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Here's my code

I seem to be getting an error `SQL command cannot be converted to string` with this code

```
Dim LogData2 As sterm.markdata = New sterm.markdata()

Dim query As New SqlCommand("Select * from openquery (db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE person=@person')")
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person", Session("number"))

Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(query)

dgBookings.DataSource = drCode2a.Tables(0).DefaultView
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

I tried adding in a `Convert.ToString` like this

```
Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(Convert.ToString(query))
```

And now I get this error

```
Could not find server 'System' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but not sure what - ASP.Net and SQL is all new to me so any help would be much appreciated.

Source code of StermQ3

```
StermQ3(String) As System.Data.DataSet

Public Function StermQ3(ByVal strSQL6 As String) As System.Data.DataSet
```

**UPDATE**

Source code as it is after some changes have been made

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)

Dim LogData2 As sterm.markdata = New sterm.markdata() 

Dim query As New SqlCommand("Select * from openquery (db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE person=@person')") 
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person", Session("number")) 
query.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
query.CommandText = "openquery"

Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(Convert.ToString(query)) 

dgBookings.DataSource = drCode2a.Tables(0).DefaultView 
dgBookings.DataBind()

End Sub
```

HTML is

```
<asp:DataGrid id="dgBookings" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeader="true">

</asp:DataGrid>
```

Old way I used to do my query

```
Dim query As String = "Select * from openquery (db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor=''" + Session("number") + "'' ')"
```

That works if i replace my SQL Command but it is open to SQL Injection

**UPDATE**

I now have it so it work without the parameters bit here's my updated souce code any idea why it won't add the parameter value?

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='server1'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'")
   conn.Open()


Dim query As New SqlCommand("Select * from openquery (db, 'Select * from table where investor = @investor ') ", conn)
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@investor", 69836)

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

It works like this

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='server1'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'")
   conn.Open()


Dim query As New SqlCommand("Select * from openquery (db, 'Select * from table where investor = 69836') ", conn)

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

Here's how i solved my issue

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='h'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'")

conn.Open()

Dim query As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @sql varchar(1000) Select @investor = 69836 select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(db,''SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor = ''''' + @investor + ''''''')' EXEC(@sql)", conn)

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Have you debugged to find out what StermQ3 does? You are passing the string reference from an SqlCommand-Object to it what might be nonsense. I think you need its `CommandText` Property, but you have a problem because you don't get the actually SQL Text what is executed on the database. The parameters are evaluated in the Database and not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you debugged to find out what StermQ3 does? You are passing the string reference from an SqlCommand-Object to it what might be nonsense. I think you need its CommandText Property, but you have a problem because you don't get the actually SQL Text what is executed on the database. The parameters are evaluated in the Database and not here.

What you can try is following:

```
 Dim commandText As String = query.CommandText
 For Each parameter As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter In query.Parameters
     commandText=commandText.Replace(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value.ToString)
 Next
 Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(commandText)
```

But i don't think that you want that, because you are again open for SQL-Injection(StermQ3 returns a Dataset). I think StermQ3 needs to get an overloaded version that takes a SQLCommand as parameter.

**EDIT**: I think the SqlCommand does not know that it should execute a StoredProcedure. Set its [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) and as CommandText the name of the SP:

```
query.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
query.CommandText = "openquery"
```

Comment: I don't actually know how to debug it - i literally know nothing about ASP.Net i've done some queries and that's about it i've been thrown in the deep end with this stuff after a guy recently left

Comment: Set a breakpoint in Visual Studio by clicking leftmost in the source-code window at the line you want to stop(Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(query)
). Then start the application and wait till it stops there. Now you can check variables etc. by hovering them, open the quick watch window(right-click on a variable) or add watches to see directly when the values are changing.
http://odetocode.com/Articles/425.aspx

Comment: I don't seem to have Visual Studio on my PC i'm guessing this is a necessity if i'm going to be able to debug?

Comment: What IDE do you have? VS 2010 Express is for free: http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/

Comment: All I know is that I do everything in Dreamweaver no other program

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783532/where-to-start-with-asp-net-in-c-and-dreamweaver

Comment: @Tim thanks for the help so far I'm all set up on VS now and i've set the breakpoint when I hover over the bit that you mentioned `query = {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand}` which is obviously why i'm getting the error. I'm not really sure what it means though? I know i need to somehow convert it into a string and pass it

Comment: @ Jamie Taylor: step into the StermQ3-Function to see what causes the exception. As i mentioned before, overload that function with one that takes a SqlCommand as parameter and all should work.
I guess that StermQ3 is creating a SQlCommand itself, that is not needed anymore when it is passed per parameter.

Comment: I had a look at StermQ3 definition and it looks like this `StermQ3(String) As System.Data.DataSet`

Comment: Yes, naturally. Add a StermQ3 function to this class which takes a SqlCommand as Parameter and copy/paste all but the creation of the SqlCommand of the old one into this new function. Then call the new function from the old. Please edit your question and add the sourcecode from the StermQ3 into it.

Comment: How do I add a StermQ3 function to that class which takes a SqlCommand as Parameter?

Comment: Show us the function and we show you how you could do that ;-)

Comment: Do I need to post more source code? Everything in my question is pretty much what I need to do?

Comment: Where is the StermQ3 Funtion(of Class markdata) in your question? There is only the call of that function!

Comment: Updated question with what I think you need? Sorry i'm not good with this

Comment: No problem. But you have only posted the signature of the function and not the function itself. Is it in another DLL you don't have the sourcecode from?

Comment: StermQ3 seems to the only DLL file it accesses?

Comment: Can you step into(F11) StermQ3 while debugging? http://odetocode.com/Articles/425.aspx
Set a breakpoint at the line `Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(query)` and hit F11 to go into the function. Then copy/paste it.

Comment: I've done what you said and hit F11 but all it says is `{"Server was unable to process request. ---> Could not find server 'System' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers."}` doesn't give me anymore info

Comment: I meant that you should debug this function to see what it is doing and copy/paste its sourcecode here(not only the signature).
Btw, have you seen what i've added to my answer?

Comment: I added the bit in that you updated your question with but still no luck - I put a breakpoint on the line that you said and stepped into it but it just gave the error above how do I get the source code which is causing the error?

Comment: 1. Update your question with your current sourcecode(it should be changed  significantly now compared to the original). 
 2. Is your Database you want to access on a remote system? I asked because openquery is made for that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx
Normally you could execute your query without that. 
 3. Add your Database Version as Tag to this question(f.e. MS SQL-Server 2005).

Comment: I've updated my question with my current source code and with the old way i wrote queries which will hopefully help.  I used to access using openquery so i think it is remote system. I don't actually know which database version we are using - sorry

Comment: Do you have an Oracle database? I wasn't familiar with the openquery command. I've read that it doesn't accept parameters, only text. So ensure that a linked server db exists and pass "Select * from openquery (db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor=''" + Session("number") + "'' ')" to StermQ3. For further informations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: I've updated my question now change the source code quite a bit seems to work without the parameter but when i try and put that it just getting a db error

Answer (score 0):

What `LogData2.StermQ3` method does? My guess that it logs query your are going to execute. If it is so, than you should save your query in different variable and pass it to the method.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what it does - i've taken over someone else's work so doing it as they did - how can i save my query in a different variable and pass it? Thanks

Comment: I think the best way to make something working right is to understand what it is doing. So you should try to find out...

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the function takes a query, not SQL command. Try the following:

```
Dim query As String = "Select * from openquery (db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE person=" & Session("number") & "')"
Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(query)

dgBookings.DataSource = drCode2a.Tables(0).DefaultView
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

Yes, it may not prevent you from SQL injections, so the best you can do in this case is to use

```
query = query.Replace("'", "''")
```

before you pass it to that function. In all other cases use parametrized queries.

Comment: By doing this it gives me a syntax error - its converting the `'` before `SELECT` to a `''` and erroring

Comment: Completely forgot about that, just ignore the last part of my answer  then =) Otherwise rewrite StermQ3 function and make it take sqlcommand instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Jamie taylor I will try to answer your question again.

You are using OpenQuery becuase you are probably using a linked DB

Basically the problem is the OpenQuery Method takes a string you cannot pass a variable as part of the string you sent to OpenQuery.

You can format your query like this instead.  The notation follows servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename.  If you are using a linked server via odbc then omit databasename and schemaname, as illustrated below

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("your SQL Connection String")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * db...table where investor = @investor"
    Dim parameter As SqlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
    parameter.DbType = SqlDbType.Int
    parameter.ParameterName = "@investor"
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    parameter.Value = 34
```